# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split' with result of input()?

Tags: python, python-2.7

**(This is Homework)** Here is what I have:

```
L1 = list(map(int, input().split(",")))
```

I am running into

```
  File "lab3.py", line 23, in <module>
    L1 = list(map(int, input().split(",")))
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'
```

what is causing this error?

I am using `1, 2, 3, 4` as input

Comment: what do input for `input()`? it is reading it as a tuple, not a list.

Comment: @RNar: `input` is a built-in.

Comment: if this is python2, use `raw_input` instead of input. Please break the problem down before posting.  What is the smallest program you can write that still demonstrates your problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  Please give us the missing code; input might help, too.

Comment: @RyanHaining this is definitely not python2, look at `print()`. And that error is not caused by using the wrong `input()`.

Comment: That said, I suspect that you should put parentheses around the input call, so it reads (input()).split(","); I think you're trying to split the functional object, rather than the return from the call.

Comment: Whatever it is that you're inputting is not in proper format. What are you enter in when you run the code?

Comment: @Leb: `print(x)` works just fine in Python 2, the extra parentheses get ignored. It's only when you're printing multiple things that the `print` statement behaves differently than the `print` function (`print(a, b)` prints a tuple in Python 2).

Comment: @Leb check again. `print(var)` is legal in python2. It reads it as a parenthesized expression. If you had `print (a, b)` it would run in 2 and 3 but give different output (2 would see it as printing a tuple)

Comment: Got it, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Leb if all I needed to do to figure out whether an OP is using 2 or 3 is to look at the `print`s it would mean a lot less guesswork

Comment: @RyanHaining I have used that before, and apparently it was just a bunch of lucky guesses.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `raw_input` instead of `input`

```
raw_input().split(",")
```

In Python 2, the `input()` function will try to `eval` whatever the user enters, the equivalent of `eval(raw_input())`. When you input a comma separated list of values, it is evaluated as a tuple. Your code then calls `split` on that tuple:

```
>>> input().split(',')
1,2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'
```

If you want to se that it's actually a tuple:

```
>>> v = input()
1,3,9
>>> v[0]
1
>>> v[1]
3
>>> v[2]
9
>>> v
(1, 3, 9)
```

Finally, rather than `list` and `map` you'd be better off with a list comprehension

```
L1 = [int(i) for i in raw_input().split(',')]
```